# auto excerpt from WYSIWYG

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg

Is it possible to grab the contents of the WYSIWYG editor and save the first 100 words into the excerpt automatically? I know about `excerpt_save_pre` which will save the excerpt when you are in the editor, but haven't seen anything that will grab the contents from the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Why are you trying to grab the content from the WYSIWYG editor? When you save your post WordPress can automatically create an excerpt with a specific length (which you can adjust in the settings menu).

Comment: Good point. I just found something which uses `&$_POST` and am looking at grabbing the content from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out. The "secret" is `&$_POST` when the post is saved/published. That builds an array which the content can be extracted and then saved to the excerpt field using `excerpt_save_pre`.

I went a little further allowing control over the number of characters or the number of words, using `$length`, and the output is controlled on which `$output` section you uncomment.

The code below tested on my vanilla site as working.

```
function auto_insert_excerpt(){
$post_data = &$_POST;
$post_content = $post_data['content'];
$length = 15;

// This will return the first $length number of CHARACTERS
//$output = (strlen($post_content) > 13) ? substr($post_content,0,$length).'...' : $post_content;

// This will return the first $length number of WORDS
$post_content_array = explode(' ',$post_content);
if(count($post_content_array) > $length && $length > 0)
    $output = implode(' ',array_slice($post_content_array, 0, $length)).'...';

return $output;
}
add_filter('excerpt_save_pre', 'auto_insert_excerpt');
```